# How to assign different fonts and size to title and axis in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

im trying to separately set the font/size for the axis and the title. Ex: For title: Font = Ariel and size = 12. For Axis: Font = Times New Roman and size = 20. Im using the following code to do it.

```
fig.update_layout(font=dict(family='Times New Roman',size=20,\
title=dict(font=dict(family='Ariel', size=12)))
```

When I do this, only the font change will take into effect and it will change everything, but title never does anything. Thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are examples of changing titles, axis labels, etc. in the official reference. Based on [this example](https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/#global-and-local-font-specification), I further changed the partial color and size of the title. This tip is referenced [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-color-in-title-text/64067/3).

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="species",
                title="Playing with <span style='font-size:22px;color:black;'>Fonts</span>")
fig.update_layout(
    font_family="Courier New",
    font_color="blue",
    title_font_family="Times New Roman",
    title_font_color="red",
    legend_title_font_color="green"
)
fig.update_xaxes(title_font_family="Arial")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To set axis tick properties, you can provide a `dict` containing one or more of the following keys:

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickfont=dict(family="CMU Sans Serif Demi Condensed",
                                 size=<SIZE>,
                                color=<COLOUR>) )

fig.update_yaxes(tickfont=dict(family="Lucida Console",
                                 size=<SIZE>,
                                color=<COLOUR>) )
```